# error when making connection with stripe in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

when changing the properties of my styles.xml as the documentation asks, I got the following error message

[image]

```
<style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
```

, i changed for:

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo: "Ligth" should be "Light".